# Adding two variables - php

Tags: php, variables, int, addition

I am in the process of designing a php validated form for a restaurant website which directs the user to a thank you page, displaying their reservation details, once they have pressed submit. Currently I have 2 variables, one named 'party', the other named 'vip'. These variables both display a string value when echoed. However, I wish to assign them an int value and then add them together to display a total price to the user.

Currently I have this code which does not seem to function:

```
<b>Total Reservation Costs: </b> £
 <?php
 if ( $party == "1 Person (+£5)" )
   {
        $party = 5;
   }
    elseif if ( $party == "2 People (+£10)" )
   {
         $party = 10;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "3 People (+£15)" )
   {
         $party = 15;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "4 People (+£20)" )
   {
         $party = 20;
   }
    elseif if ( $party == "5 People (+£25)" )
   {
        $party = 25;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "6 People (+£30)" )
   {
        $party = 30;
   }
    elseif if ( $party == "7 People (+£35)" )
   {
        $party = 35;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "8 People (+£40)" )
   {
        $party = 40;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "9 People (+£45)" )
   {
        $party = 45;
   }
   elseif if ( $party == "10+ People (+£50)" )
   {
        $party = 50;
   }

 if ( $vip == "Yes" )
   {
        $vip = 5;
   }
    elseif if ( $vip == "No" )
   {
        $vip = 0;
   }

 echo $party + $vip;
?>
```

If anyone knows how I can get this to work I would be very grateful, I am new to web languages so I apologise in advance if my answer isn't very clear. Thank you.

Comment: ummm `elseif if` I guess it works but it's not what you mean to write.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a string to determine the number of people why not just use an int

Here is a complete program

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="party">
        <option value="1">1 People (+£5)</option> 
        <option value="2">2 People (+£10)</option>
        <!-- ... -->
        <option value="10">10+ People (+£50)</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vip" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Reservation" /> 
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['party']) && is_numeric($_POST['party'])) {
    $party = (int)$_POST['party'];
    $vip = isset($_POST['vip']) ? 5 : 0;
    echo "Total is: " . (($party * 5) + $vip);
}
```

and `elseif if` should be just `else if`

Comment: Because as the user is displayed their reservation details I wish for them to be told on page "Party size: 4 people (+£20)". I then wish to take this 20 from their selection and add it to the 5 if they have selected VIP area seating. Although, if you have a simplified method to make this work, please let me know

Comment: @JamesPatterson please see the updated answer for a nice way of implementing your form and form substitution script.

Comment: I applied your suggestions however I still am not presented with a total cost :( Although, no errors are thrown up either. Why might this be happening?

Comment: @JamesPatterson Yeah, `is_int` should have been `is_numeric`. Give it a go now.

Comment: Still the same result, also I notice that after the "Total Reservation Costs: " line, the page is cut off? :(

Comment: @JamesPatterson I have updated the answer one last time for you. I am not debugging your entire site. My answer is sufficient to solve the problem outlined by your question. Please accept it.

Comment: I commented with the full code so that you could get a better idea of how this can work, and if errors were present which could be affecting your solution. Either way your answer has not provided with me a solution to my problem so I will not accept it. I appreciate the help you have given me but I do not appreciate your rudeness.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elseif if, its elseif

```
Total Reservation Costs:  £
<?php
    if ( $party == "1 Person (+£5)" ){
    $party = 5;
    }
    elseif( $party == "2 People (+£10)" ){
    $party = 10;
    }
    elseif( $party == "3 People (+£15)" ){
    $party = 15;
    }
    elseif( $party == "4 People (+£20)" ){
    $party = 20;
    }
    elseif( $party == "5 People (+£25)" ){
    $party = 25;
    }
    elseif ( $party == "6 People (+£30)" ){
    $party = 30;
    }
    elseif( $party == "7 People (+£35)" ){
    $party = 35;
    }
    elseif( $party == "8 People (+£40)" ){
    $party = 40;
    }
    elseif( $party == "9 People (+£45)" ){
    $party = 45;
    }
    elseif( $party == "10+ People (+£50)" ){
    $party = 50;
    }
    else{    $party = 0;
    }
    if ( $vip == "Yes" ){
    $vip = 5;
    }
    elseif ( $vip == "No" ){
    $vip = 0;
    }
    else{
    $vip = 0;
    }
    echo $party + $vip;
?>
```

`

I'd suggest adding an else statement too, as i have added in my answer, to handle any other cases that might occur.

Comment: Hi friend, I tried your suggestion however I just got no such variable errors on screen once the thank you page loads. Why might this be happening? :(

Comment: I get an "Notice: Undefined variable: party in" error on each line the $party is mentioned in your code and also an "Notice: Undefined variable: vip" error where $vip is mentioned :(

Comment: did you initialize thos variables as per your code `$party = $_POST['party'];
$vip = isset($_POST['vip']) ? 5 : 0;` ?

Comment: Sorry I am really new to weblanguages, can you explain what  you mean by this? For help, here is my reservations page in its entirety: pastebin.com/UNDkAEYT - here is also my thank you page in its entirety: pastebin.com/31pdBnD5