# Adding variables based on user selection

Tags: php, forms, addition

I have created a reservations page for a restaurant website, with a form present to book a dinner reservation. It contains a dropdown box which allows the user to select the amount of people who will be dining in their party. It also contains a radio button to allow the user to select if they wish to be seated in the VIP area.

Once the form validation is successful, the user will be sent to a confirmation page, where the reservation details they have entered, will be displayed to them.

Each person in the party should cost an extra £5 towards their booking fee and if they wish to be seated in the VIP area, they will be charged an additional £5.

I wish to add these two factors together and display a total booking fee to the user on the confirmation page, but the code I have currently, is not performing this.

Here is the relevant code on my reservations page:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['party'] = $_POST['party'];
}

 if ( !empty($_POST['vip'])) 
    $_SESSION['vip'] = $_POST['vip'];
?>

...

 <strong>Select Party Size* :</strong>
 <br>
 <select name="party" id="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
 <option value="">Please Select</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="1") echo "selected";?> value="1">1 Person (+£5)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="2") echo "selected";?> value="2">2 People (+£10)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="3") echo "selected";?> value="3">3 People (+£15)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="4") echo "selected";?> value="4">4 People (+£20)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="5") echo "selected";?> value="5">5 People (+£25)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="6") echo "selected";?> value="6">6 People (+£30)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="7") echo "selected";?> value="7">7 People (+£35)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="8") echo "selected";?> value="8">8 People (+£40)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="9") echo "selected";?> value="9">9 People (+£45)</option>
 <option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="10") echo "selected";?> value="10">10+ People (+£50)</option>
 </select>

 <strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
 Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">
 <br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
 No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">
```

Here is the relevant code on my confirmation page:

```
<b>Total Reservation Costs: </b> £
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['party']) && is_numeric($_POST['party'])) {
     $party = (int)$_POST['party'];
     $vip = isset($_POST['vip']) ? 5 : 0;
     echo "Total is: " . (($party * 5) + $vip);
}
?>
```

Currently no calculation is echoed, would anyone be able to correct my code so I can understand what I did wrong? Thank you

Comment: Is "Total is:" echoed?

Comment: @dan08 No, it is not

Comment: I thought my answer was not helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050838/adding-two-variables-php/27050899#27050899

Comment: @robbmj clearly you can't read. I thanked you for your help, if you recall I wasn't impressed with your rudeness.

Comment: Your quote `"your answer has not provided with me a solution to my problem"`. Clearly it answered your question as you have copied it into this one and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078470/php-calculation-from-html-form. Note how your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050838/adding-two-variables-php) made no mention of `sessions`. S.O. is not a place to have people write your entire application for you. A point I tried to make before when you sent me links to pastebin and asked me to fit my answer into the rest of your code.

Comment: @robbmj You cant TELL me to accept your answer if it hasn't provided me with a solution to my problem. How pathetic that you're trying to fight me over this. Some people amaze me.

Comment: When someone says "please" they are not telling you to do something.

Comment: But there is one more point to be made, when you ask a question you get an answer specific to the question. Not one that includes sessions, multiple pages or whatever else your application needs to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we'd need to see the "user is sent to the confirmation page" portion of the application, but if you validate and then redirect user to a new page, the $_POST global will be empty.  It appears you're pushing POST into SESSION, so maybe something like this instead:

```
<b>Total Reservation Costs: </b> £
<?php
     if (isset($_SESSION['party']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['party'])) {
         $party = (int)$_SESSION['party'];
         $vip = isset($_SESSION['vip']) ? 5 : 0;
         echo "Total is: " . (($party * 5) + $vip);
     }
?>
```

Also, just as an aside - you might not want to shove unvalidated $POST information into $SESSION for your application's security.  Validate the $POST information, then push it into $SESSION

Comment: This seems to be working however the total cost echoed isnt correct, maybe theres an mistake in your calculation somewhere? :( Eg. if i put 1 person (£5) and yes to vip (£5), £30 total cost is displayed

Comment: Actually oddly enough it seems to be working now? not sure why I first got an incorrect price

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working!  The difference you're seeing may be because of data that was inside of SESSION before-hand, since the session is PHP's attempt at being stateful. Also please give some though to what @AdamMacDonald had to say regarding hardening your post parameters. Never trust user entered data!

Comment: Just noticed it still adds 5 to the vip even if it has been checked as no, is there a way I can fix this? Thanks so much for all of your feedback, I really appreciate it. I will take into consideration what you have told me

Comment: No problem. So check out the function isset() on php.net when you get a chance - knowing how isset vs. empty vs. is_null etc. will be something that you'll have to deal with all the time.  isset() will return true if the variable is set AND isn't null - so if it's empty, it will still resolve as true.  Try (isset($_SESSION['vip'] ) && $_SESSION['vip'] == 1)) in your ternary operator.

Comment: whoops, just glanced at your code - $_SESSION['vip'] == 'Yes', I mean

Comment: thanks for your reply again! Could you explain more where I should implement these changes? I am new to php so its quite difficult for me to understand, sorry

Comment: I think I have implemented your suggestions properly and now the total price wont display if "No" for vip area is checked :(

Comment: still had no luck in fixing this issue, do you have any other suggestions? :(

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple problems that may be contributing to the calculation being echoed.

First, change

```
<select name="party" id="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
```

to

```
<select name="party" id="party">
```

since your value is coming from the option list.

Next, change:

```
(isset($party) && $party=="1")
```

to

```
(isset($_SESSION['party']) && $_SESSION['party']=="1")
```

Third, you way want to harden your post parameters .. something like this maybe:

```
$_SESSION['party'] = htmlentities($_POST['party'],ENT_QUOTES);
```